Read previous and next two rows from particular index wherever conditions are met from pandas dataframe
I am looking for a solution to read previous two rows where C_1=104 and next two rows where C_1=105 includes these 2 rows as well. Below are the different dataframe inputs.
The challenge I am facing is:
Cond 1 - sometimes C_1=104 is first row(refer df2) in dataframe so there wouldn't be any previous rows.
Cond 2 -  sometime C_1=104 is not there but C_1=105 is first row(refer df3).
Cond 3- sometimes Cond-1 & 2 can be other way which means C_1=105 can be last row(refer df4) OR C_1=104 can we last(C_1=105 will not be there).
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
      datetime        C_1 C_2  C_3  C_4
"18/06/2023 3:51:50"  101 128  89    4  
"18/06/2023 3:51:52"  102 128  61    4  
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  103 130  65    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  104 132  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  105 134  66    2  
"18/06/2023 3:51:55"  106 134  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  107 156  77    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  108 112  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:57"  109 109  90    0  
"""), sep="\s+")

df-1 Output-
      datetime        C_1 C_2  C_3  C_4
"18/06/2023 3:51:52"  102 128  61    4 
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  103 130  65    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  104 132  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  105 134  66    2  
"18/06/2023 3:51:55"  106 134  89    0 
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  107 156  77    0

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
      datetime        C_1 C_2  C_3  C_4  
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  104 132  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  105 134  66    2  
"18/06/2023 3:51:55"  106 134  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  107 156  77    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  108 112  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:57"  109 109  90    0  
"""), sep="\s+")

df-2 Output-
      datetime        C_1 C_2  C_3  C_4
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  104 132  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  105 134  66    2  
"18/06/2023 3:51:55"  106 134  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  107 156  77    0

df3 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
      datetime        C_1 C_2  C_3  C_4   
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  105 134  66    2  
"18/06/2023 3:51:55"  106 134  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  107 156  77    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  108 112  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:57"  109 109  90    0  
"""), sep="\s+")

df-3 Output-
      datetime        C_1 C_2  C_3  C_4  
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  105 134  66    2  
"18/06/2023 3:51:55"  106 134  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  107 156  77    0

df4 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
      datetime        C_1 C_2  C_3  C_4
"18/06/2023 3:51:50"  101 128  89    4  
"18/06/2023 3:51:52"  102 128  61    4  
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  103 130  65    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  104 132  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  105 134  66    2  
"""), sep="\s+")

df-4 Output-
      datetime        C_1 C_2  C_3  C_4
"18/06/2023 3:51:52"  102 128  61    4 
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  103 130  65    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  104 132  89    0  
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  105 134  66    2

I found some solution, still looking for better way to achieve it -
idx1 = df1[(df1['C_1'] == 104) & (df1['C_2'] == 132)].index
idx2 = df1[(df1['C_1'] == 105) & (df1['C_2'] == 134)].index
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
if idx1.size != 0:
    df_1 = df1.loc[idx1[0]-2:idx1[0], :]
if idx2.size != 0:
    df_2 = df1.loc[idx2[0]:idx2[0]+2, :]

df_merged = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], ignore_index=True).sort_values(by='datetime')

